# Keyboard and mouse not responsive in Desktop Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Ubuntu 22.04.2

The keyboard works fine for the BIOS and for Ubuntu Server (no GUI) but when I enabled the GUI keyboard and mouse stops (sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop). Also the keyboard stops when Ubuntu Desktop is fresh installed.  Except for the CTRL key.  This will blank the screen.  The mouse is also frozen.

What is kinda interesting is moving the mouse, blanking and un-blanking the screen, the mouse is frozen again, but in the new position.

Keyboard and mouse work booting from the Ubuntu CD. I am using an HP Proliant DL360 G5.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aquire ssh access via PuTTY
2. Using the instructions here, boot the system into cli mode:

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/boot-ubuntu-20-04-command-console/

3. Reboot, then logon and use "startx" to start up the x-window system.